# C# - Sql Query If Where Clause is there then working if not there no result

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Please solve my problem

I have following Code

```js
jQuery.ajax({                
                type: 'POST',
                url: "Default.aspx/populate_From",
                data: JSON.stringify({ term: aterm }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);

                    //jQuery(containerFrom).html(data.d);
                    //forceWidth(containerFrom, jQuery(containerFrom).width());
                },
                error: function (x, e) {
                    alert(e.Message);
                    alert(jsonResponse.message);
                    jQuery(containerFrom).text("Error, unable to retrieve list.");
                }
            });
```

```html
[WebMethod]
    public static string populate_From(string term)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM route_onlinemaptable WHERE isdelete = 0 AND (route_from LIKE '" + term + "%' OR map_from LIKE '" + term + "%') ORDER BY priority DESC, state_from ASC, map_from ASC";
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(term))
        {
            query = "SELECT * FROM route_onlinemaptable";
        }
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query); 
        return GetData(cmd).GetXml();
    }

    public static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnStrng"].ConnectionString;   
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Query = SELECT * FROM route_onlinemaptable --> Not Showing Any Result 
If Query = SELECT * FROM route_onlinemaptable where route_from = 'SOME VALUE' --> Showing Result

My Database is Attached to Application & Table Contains nearly 500 - 600 Rows.

Please kindly suggest any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

please add one condition

check if term is null or empty then dont append where condition

```
string query = "";
    if(term = "")
    query = "SELECT * FROM route_onlinemaptable WHERE isdelete = 0"
    else
    query = "SELECT * FROM route_onlinemaptable WHERE isdelete = 0 AND (route_from LIKE '" + term + "%' OR map_from LIKE '" + term + "%') ORDER BY priority DESC, state_from ASC, map_from ASC";
```

Comment: Hi Aarif, It is not working even directly passed query = "SELECT * FROM route_onlinemaptable"

Comment: Hi Aarif, It executing but that web method response not getting to ajax success function it is going to error function.

Comment: changed dataType: "json" to dataType: "xml" and check again.

Comment: Hi Aarif, It is not working even I put dataType: "xml"                                     If Select Top 10 rows then it is working                              I am not getting entire data

Comment: so may be its possible that there is some data which are responsible for error. try to Select Top 100 then 200 and so on to get idea for this issue.

Comment: Hi Aarif, Thank you. I will try this method